# Roblox - attempt to index field '?' (a nil value) Issue with running a module function

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a datastore and change the value of player data, but I am having an issue getting the script to run the function. I will paste the code I'm having issues with and mark the lines giving errors. I apologize for any rookie mistakes, this'll be my first time programming a game with Lua and on Roblox. I think it may be an issue with how I call the `statName` and how a `statName` of `"Wheat"` isn't there, but I don't know how to call it otherwise, or why it isn't there.

This is the relevant stuff from the modulescript:

```
function PlayerStatManager:ChangeStat(player, statName, value)

    local playerUserId = "Player_" .. player.UserId
    assert(typeof(sessionData[playerUserId][statName]) == typeof(value), "ChangeStat error: types do not match")  <--this line
    if typeof(sessionData[playerUserId][statName]) == "number" then
        sessionData[playerUserId][statName] = sessionData[playerUserId][statName] + value
    else
        sessionData[playerUserId][statName] = value
    end

end


-- Function to add player to the 'sessionData' table

local function setupPlayerData(player)

    local playerUserId = "Player_" .. player.UserId
    local data
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        playerData:UpdateAsync(playerUserId, function(playerData)
            data = playerData
        end)
    end)

    if success then
        if data then
            -- Data exists for this player
            sessionData[playerUserId] = data
        else
            -- Data store is working, but no current data for this player
            sessionData[playerUserId] = {Money=0, Wheat=0, Silo=0, Feeders=0, Chickens=0}
        end
    else
        warn("Cannot set up data for player!")
    end
end
```

This is the relevant stuff from the script using the modulescript:

```
local SrvrStats = require(game.ServerStorage.moduleScript)

SrvrStats:ChangeStat(player, 'Wheat', playerWheat.Value) <-- this line
```

Comment: The error message means `sessionData[playerUserId]` is `nil`

Comment: Probably, `setupPlayerData` hadn't been invoked prior to `ChangeStat` invocation

Comment: You are correct, the playerAdded command, which would then start the setupPlayerData,  was not firing when I'd test it because apparently the :GetAsync and :UpdateAsync methods take a while to execute, which prevents it from knowing that it is supposed to fire before a player joins. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the full module? I don't see when the module fires setupPlayerData function. And, what does the module return?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
local PlayerStatManager = {}

PlayerStatManager.ChangeStat = function(player, statName, value)

    local playerUserId = "Player_" .. player.UserId
    assert(typeof(sessionData[playerUserId][statName]) == typeof(value), "ChangeStat error: types do not match")  <--this line
    if typeof(sessionData[playerUserId][statName]) == "number" then
        sessionData[playerUserId][statName] = sessionData[playerUserId][statName] + value
    else
        sessionData[playerUserId][statName] = value
    end

end


-- Function to add player to the 'sessionData' table

PlayerStatManager.setupPlayerData = PlayerStatManager(player)

    local playerUserId = "Player_" .. player.UserId
    local data
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        playerData:UpdateAsync(playerUserId, function(playerData)
            data = playerData
        end)
    end)

    if success then
        if data then
            -- Data exists for this player
            sessionData[playerUserId] = data
        else
            -- Data store is working, but no current data for this player
            sessionData[playerUserId] = {Money=0, Wheat=0, Silo=0, Feeders=0, Chickens=0}
        end
    else
        warn("Cannot set up data for player!")
    end
end

return PlayerStatManager
```